# Making a bookmark using AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So I'm trying to make a bookmark and to pass a number to PHP through javascript and these dont seem to work

```
function bookmark() { 
    var issue = "<?php echo $path; ?>";
    var name = "<?php echo $comicName; ?>";
    var mark = index;
    window.location.href = "UploadedComicViewer.php?issue=" +issue+ "&amp;comic=" +name+ "&amp;page=" + mark; 
}

$(".bookmark").on( 'click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'UploadedComicViewer.php',
        data: {
            issue: "some text",
            name: "some text 2",
            page: index
        },
        success: function( data ) {
            console.log( data );
        }
    });
});
```

The $path and $comicName are variables that hold a value I got using $_GET

Comment: do you know how ajax works?

Comment: Can  you send whole code, please?

Answer (score 0):

You use "POST" ajax request, not "GET".
You should retrieve variables via $_POST global variable.